# Catching global error from Express with Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I'm trying to catch an error on client-side which comes from Express. I'm using the Rate Limiter package to limit requests on a given route.
Basically, its throwing a 429 error when the number of requests is reached.

```
const limiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
  max: 100 // limit each IP to 100 requests per windowMs
});
```

So I'm adding this middleware to my route, but on the client side, when the error is fired in the logs, the error scope of Angular (below) doesnt catch it.

HttpClient

```
 public login(user): Observable<any> {
return this.http.post('/api/login');
}
```

Component

```
 this.auth.login(credentials).subscribe( 
    (success) => {if everything is fine},
    (error) => {catch the error message here of 429 error request}
    )
```

How could I proceed to catch it more globally but still related within a specific function on the HttpClient in Angular?

Thanks in advance

Comment: create shared service and handle it there, call that service from all components.
OR create interceptor and handle it there check this https://scotch.io/@vigneshsithirai/angular-6-7-http-client-interceptor-with-error-handling

Comment: @RahulSharma thanks for the info i'm going to check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if I understand your question correctly, you may try using an http interceptor:

```
@Injectable()
export class ExampleInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

constructor() { }

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  return next.handle(req.clone()).pipe(
    tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
    // if everything is fine...
    }, (err: any) => {
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        if (err.status === 429) {
            // if the relevant error is thrown...
        }
      }
    }))
 }
}
```

and load that interceptor in your module's providers like

```
 {
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: ExampleInterceptor
 }
```

Comment: Yeah thanks you understood correctly. The error will be throwed but how can I catch it in my component.ts or service?

Comment: Alright nvm I found, just doing a function call right after the if statement, seems logic... Thanks for you help!